ros2 launch: Remap topics from command line
In ROS2, we can remap topics from command line with ros2 run:
ros2 run remap_test pub --ros-args --remap old_topic:=new_topic

However, the equivalent with ros2 launch does not work even though it was possible with ROS1:
ros2 launch remap_test launchfile.py --ros-args --remap old_topic:=new_topic


ros2: error: unrecognized arguments: --ros-args --remap
old_topic:=new_topic

A workaround would be to declare arguments in the launch file:
def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'remap_from',
            description='Topic to remap from'
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'remap_to',
            description='Topic to remap to'
        ),
        Node(
            package='remap_test',
            executable='pub',
            name='remap_test_node',
            output='screen',
            remappings=[
                (LaunchConfiguration('remap_from'), LaunchConfiguration('remap_to')),
            ],
        ),
    ])

Then we can use the following launch command:
ros2 launch remap_test launchfile.py  remap_from:=old_topic remap_to:=new_topic

This works fine, but is inconvenient. If there are multiple topics to be remapped, we need to specify each one as an argument.
Is there a more flexible solution that I am missing? Perhaps similar to the ros2 run command?
This also implies that we cannot remap topics from launch files that we don't have access to, unless we use a wrapper launch file, right?
